# In JavaScript, how can I use regex to match unless words are in a list of excluded words?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I use regex to match any word (\w) except a list of certain words? For example:

I want to match the words `use` and `utilize` and any words after it except if the words are `something` or `fish`.

```
use this  <-- match
utilize that  <-- match
use something   <-- don't want to match this
utilize fish <-- don't want to match this
```

How do I specify a list of words I don't want to match against?

Comment: What language? It matters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to determine that the word you are about to match is not a particular thing. You can use the following regex to do this:

```
(use|utilize)\s(?!fish|something)(\w+)
```

This will match "use" or "utilize" followed by a space, and then if the following word is not "fish" or "something", it will match that next word.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up combining the negative look-ahead items like so: `(?!fish|something)`.

Comment: It looks like that does work. I thought there was a problem with variable width lookarounds, but it seems that that only applies to lookbehinds.

Comment: But this wont match `use fish`. I am having the same problem where for example i want to match `treatment` but not `genetic treatment`. Match a list of words, but exclude a combination of words

Comment: @vinay You'd need to add terms that would otherwise match to an exclusion list. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34816310/1301972) below for a solution that would work if `"genetic"` was a search term while `"genetic treatment"` was an excluded term.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
/(?:use|utilize)\s+(?!something|fish)\w+/
```

Answer (score 3):

### Don't Hard-Code Your Regular Expressions

Rather than trying to put all your search and exclusion terms into a single, hard-coded regular expression, it's often more maintainable (and certainly more readable) to use short-circuit evaluation to *select* strings that match desirable terms, and then *reject* strings that contain undesirable terms.

You can then encapsulate this testing into a function that returns a Boolean value based on the run-time values of your arrays. For example:

```
'use strict';

// Join arrays of terms with the alternation operator.
var searchTerms   = new RegExp(['use', 'utilize'].join('|'));
var excludedTerms = new RegExp(['fish', 'something'].join('|'));

// Return true if a string contains only valid search terms without any
// excluded terms.
var isValidStr = function (str) {
    return (searchTerms.test(str) && !excludedTerms.test(str));
};

isValidStr('use fish');       // false
isValidStr('utilize hammer'); // true
```

Comment: This is good advice thank you, but keep in mind that in almost all cases I (and many others on SO) simplify their questions down to the most basic problem in order to make it easy to understand and for others to answer. In this case, the question was simply about a regex pattern and not the best way to implement regex in a maintainable way.

Answer (score -6):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”
>
> Now they have two problems.

Regular expressions are suited to match regular sequences of symbols, not words. Any lexer+parser would be much more suitable. For example, the grammar for this task will look very simple in Antlr. If you can't afford a learning curve behind lexers/parsers (they are pretty easy for your given task), then splitting your text into words with regular expression, and then simple search with look-ahead of 1 would be enough.

Regular expressions with words get very complex very fast. They are hard to read and hard to mantain.

Update:
Thanks for all the downvotes. Here's an example of what I meant.

```
import re

def Tokenize( text ):
    return re.findall( "\w+", text )

def ParseWhiteListedWordThenBlackListedWord( tokens, whiteList, blackList ):
    for i in range( 0, len( tokens ) - 1 ):
        if tokens[i] in whiteList and tokens[i + 1] not in blackList:
            yield ( tokens[i], tokens[i + 1] )
```

Here is some performance testing:

```
>>> timeit.timeit( 'oldtime()', 'from __main__ import oldtime', number=1 )
0.02636446265387349

>>> timeit.timeit( 'oldtime()', 'from __main__ import oldtime', number=1000 )
28.80968123656703

>>> timeit.timeit( 'newtime()', 'from __main__ import newtime', number=100 )
44.24506212427741

>>> timeit.timeit( 'newtime11()', 'from __main__ import newtime11', number=1 ) +
timeit.timeit( 'newtime13()', 'from __main__ import newtime13', number=1000 )
103.07938725936083

>>> timeit.timeit( 'newtime11()', 'from __main__ import newtime11', number=1 ) + 
timeit.timeit( 'newtime12()', 'from __main__ import newtime12', number=1000 )
0.3191265909927097
```

Some notes:
testing was over the English text of Pride anf Prejudice by Jane Austin, first words were 'Mr' and 'my', second words were 'Bennet' and 'dear'.

oldtime() is regular expression.
newtime() is Tokenizer+Parser , mind that it was run 100 times, not 1000, so, a comparable time for it would be ~442.

The next two test are to simulate repeated runs of Parser over the same text, as you reuse Tokenizer results.

newtime11() is Tokenizer only.
newtime13() is Parser with results converted to list (to simulate traversal of the results).
newtime12() is just Parser.

Well, regular expressions are faster, by quite a lot in the case of a single pass, even in the case of generator (the bulk of the time is spent tokenizing text, in case of Tokenizer+Parser). But generator expressions are extremely fast when you can reuse tokenized text and evaluate parser results lazily.

There is quite a bit of performance optimization possible, but it'll complicate the solution, possibly to the point where regular expressions are to become the best implementation.

The tokenizer+parser approach has both advantages and disadvantages:
- the structure of the solution is more complex (more elements) but each element is simpler
- elements are easy to test, including automatic testing
- it IS slow, but it gets better with reusing the same text and evaluating results lazily
- due to generators and lazy evaluation, some work may be avoided
- it is trivial to change white list and/or black list
- it is trivial to have several white lists, several black lists and/or their combinations
- it is trivial to add new parsers reusing tokenizer results

Now to that thorny You Aint Gonna Need It question. Neither you are gonna need the solution to the original question, unless it is a part of a bigger task. And that bigger task should dictate the best approach.

Update: There is a good discussion of regualr expressions in lexing and parsing at http://commandcenter.blogspot.ru/2011/08/regular-expressions-in-lexing-and.html. I'll summarize it with a quote

> Encouraging regular expressions as a panacea for all text processing 
>   problems is not only lazy and poor engineering, it also reinforces 
>   their use by people who shouldn't be using them at all.