# RegEx how to properly use OR pipelines

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string, character

I need to know how to properly use "OR" when it comes to individual characters and whole phrases... For example I have code that is checking for any number of characters OR words that are found in an array...

I want to check for some unicode characters and also some html lines of code.

I'm currently just checking for the characters using this:

```
([\u200b\u200c\u200d\0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7]*)
```

(the backslashes are representing the unicode characters `u+200b` - `u+200d` and the special characters in my software `\0-\7` (*They are all individual characters*), these are valid escape sequences in Objective-C.)

Now what if I wanted to check for these characters AND check for phrases like `<b>` or `<font color="#FF0000">`

I found stuff while doing research that said to use pipelines `|` but I'm not sure if I put them only in-between the words or also in-between the individual characters and I'm not sure if I put quotes around the words or what not... I need help before I screw this up badly haha!

(p.s., not sure if it will be any different but I'm also doing it for this:

```
([^\u200b\u200c\u200d\0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7])
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I forgot SO allows HTML ;) haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's be someting like

```
/([^....]|\<b\/\>|\<font color .... \>)/
```

though, the usual caveats about [regexes and html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068) apply here.

As for the confusion about where to put the `|`, consider this this hackneyed example: You want to find the word `color`, but also want to accommodate the british spelling, `colour`:

```
/(color|colour)/
/(colou?r)/
/(colo(r|ur))/
```

are all basically equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the british spelling! Fortunately I am assured that it will always be the exact string `<font color="#00FF00">` (or 8 other specific variants) since it is generated with another piece of software

Comment: What does this mean? `\<b\/\>` Does that become `<b>` or `<b/>`?

Comment: backslash escapes metachars. some regex engines use `<` and `>` for various things, and `/` is generally the regex delimiter, so I escape them all out of habit.

Comment: I'm confused what the ellipses are in your code... do the dots just represent what I had typed I just need to copy in paste them in there or is that some type of code in RegEx (Sorry I'm new to RegEx and last time I removed some periods from example code it stopped working haha)

Comment: Is this what I would do then? (Also do I have to backslash escape a pound sign or an equals sign?) ... `([^[\u200b\u200c\u200d\0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7]|\<b\>|\<font color=\"#FF0000\"\>])`

Comment: To check for anything but "u+200b" , "u+200c", etc. and ALSO anything but "`<b>`", "`<font color=#00FF00>`", etc.

Comment: yeah, the ellipses are what you typed. I'm lazy :)

Comment: Haha! Okay great! And do you know if I have to escape the pound sign (#) or the Equal sign?

Comment: normally, no, but depends on how you've set up your regexes. e.g. using `#` as the delimiter means you'd have to escape #'s anywhere inside the regex.

Comment: Okay, good! so the code worked perfectly except sometimes when It's checking for anything but what I listed it grabs things 3 characters long or x characters long (If I have the `<b>` tag which is 3 characters than it will grab the first set of 3 characters after that)... how can I make it check (^...) but only 1 character... part of me feels like you use a "?" or "{1}" or something (again I'm new to RegEx... it's my second day 0:) haha!

Comment: In your code I think the carrot top (^) might be on the wrong spot... I'm getting a lot of errors now /:

Comment: Found out what was wrong... I was using `[^...]` to check anything but a character... but since I know have phrases I had to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854817/regex-match-words-except-these