# get the first `content word` in a sentence in php

Tags: php

Suppose I have a sentence:

```
$str="Some remarks on singular solutions of a nonlinear equation";
```

How can I get the first content word of `$str`?  Here I call a word is a contentword if it is a noun, thus they are:

`remarks`, `singular`, `solutions`, `equation`

and the rest are considered as function word.

**UPDATE**
Suppose we have the list of function word

```
$fword=array("some","on","of", "a");
```

Comment: Do you have a source containing these words? (array, database, external file, etc.) Or are you asking how to determine if a word is a "content" or "function" word?

Comment: Finally, I solve it with: `\b(?!on|of|a|Some|one|two)(\w+)\b`, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854817/regex-match-words-except-these

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function and split the string by an interval.

> *explode* — Split a string by string
>
> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

```
$str = "Some remarks on singular solutions of a nonlinear equation";
$arr = explode(' ', trim($str));
// And then for each word in $arr check if it passes your criteria
```

If you want to know if the word is noun or not then check each word from `$arr` in `WordNet Project` http://sourceforge.net/projects/wnsqlbuilder/files/wnsqldatabase/ or some similar database with English word types.

Comment: But I need `remarks` in fact, since `some` is considered as a `function word`

Comment: What do you mean by function word and content word? Can you tell them apart if you have all the words, because `explode` will provide you all words in the sentence.

Comment: I've improved my answer. Hope it helps!