# Regex - All valid identifiers except for a given word?

Tags: java, regex, scala

Say I want a regex that accepts all valid identifiers (e.g. `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*`) except a given word (e.g. "foo").  Words with "foo" as part of the word, e.g. "foobar", are fine.  I tried using negative look-aheads and look-behinds, but am struggling because I want to allow words like "foobar" which would be disallowed by a negative look-ahead.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you really need to do it with regex?

Comment: here the [useful example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854877/2749470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below.

```
^(?!foo$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

`(?!foo$)` negative lookahead at the start asserts that the line won't contain the exact string `foo`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/1)

```
String s[] = {"foobar", "foo", "bar", "foom", "mfoo"};
for(String i: s)
{
    System.out.println(i.matches("(?!foo$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!foo$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Just add a lookahead.The lookahead will check if the word is not `foo`.

or

```
^(?!foo\\b)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/2

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this - wasn't me.  The context for this question is an attempt to modify the definition of `ident` in Scala's JavaTokenParsers trait - I'll see if it works for me there.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but how can there be any `\b` in `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$` ?

Comment: @anubhava edited.......just missed it.Btw it will work as `\b` also counts for `word boudnary at end`

Comment: ok good enough, upvoted to remove an unnecessary downvote by someone

Answer (score 1):

While both other answers are right but looks like all you need is this condition:

```
input != "foo"
```

if this is indeed the case why not **keep it simple** and use this condition:

```
( !input.equals("foo") && input.matches( "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" ) )
```

Comment: The circumstances in which this problem arises don't allow me to do that, but if I can find a way to do something like this I will.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i am making it any complex, but if you want to get word by word then the regex will look like:

```
((?!(?:\s|^)foo\s)(?:\s|^)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?=\s|$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vE4jY2/1)

It will get check all the word in the sentence.